# Flux through a Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Studying for the GRE, haven't seen a problem like this for a while:

What is the value of the flux of the vector field $\textbf{F}$, defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\textbf{F} (x, y, z)  =  x\textbf{i} + y\textbf{j} + z\textbf{k}$, through the
  surface $z=\sqrt{   1  + x^2  + y^2}$ oriented with upward-pointing normal vector field? (Note: $\textbf{i}$, $\textbf{j}$, and $\textbf{k}$ are the standard basis vectors in  $\mathbb{R}^3$. )

We've tried using $\int\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{A}$ and polar coordinates, I'm not sure where we went wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it went wrong? Do you have the answer? You got something different?

Comment: The answer is $2\pi$, but I can't figure out how to get there.

Comment: @DonAntonio I get a hyperboloid

Comment: @Rafa Of course, you're right! I got the signs messed up...hehe. Thanks!

Comment: @DonAntonio, the integral seems to diverge. Maybe a limiting range is needed...

Comment: @RafaBudría Indeed so. Clearly the (double sheeted) hyperboloid opens up over the plane $\;z=0\;$ all the way to infinity. That can't converge imo, too.

Comment: Might it make more sense to instead apply the Divergence Theorem? The cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ seems to appeal nicely to the geometry of the problem. The region enclosed by the cone and hyperbola is not compact, of coarse, which could cause some issues.

Comment: After going through the computations, the Divergence Theorem Approach also results in a diverging integral.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrize the cone with
\begin{cases}
x=x\\
y=y \\
z=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}
\end{cases}
with $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. The flux equals
\begin{align}
&\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \pmatrix{x\\y\\\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\cdot  \pmatrix{1\\0\\\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}} \times \pmatrix{0\\1\\\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}}\; dxdy 
\\&= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \pmatrix{x\\y\\\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\cdot  \pmatrix{\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\\\frac{-y}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\\1}\; dxdy
\\& =\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}  \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}-\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\; dxdy
\\&= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}  \frac{-x^2-y^2+(1+x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}\; dxdy
\\ & = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\; dr d\theta
\\ & = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} 2\pi (\sqrt{R^2+1}-1) = \infty
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe is a good problem try to find some simple contour to get $2\pi$, so is $R=\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Is it possible that OP forgot to mention something in the question, e.g., "find the flux through the surface bounded by the cone and the plane $z=2$" ?

Comment: Yes. In that case, maybe the flux through the plane must be included. Who knows, so many OP's forgot the question once the homework expired...